# cin>>a>>b; wrong in C++

Tags: c++

Is strange that I can't not find any problem, but it just crashes. In code line 22 , where the wrong happen. When input the second line of a pair of number, the program crash.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    int n, e, s, u, v;
    int* martix = nullptr, *mask = nullptr;
    for(int i = 0; i<t; i++){
        cin>>n>>e>>s;
        martix = new int[n*n];
        mask = new int[n];
        for(int i = 0; i<n*n; i++){
            mask[i] = 0;
            for(int j = 0; j<n; j++){
                martix[i*n+j] = 0;
            }
        }

        while (e--){
            cin>>u>>v;//when inputing this two int variable in second time, program crashes
            martix[u*n+v] = 1;
            martix[v*n+u] = 1;
        }

        cout<<s<<' ';
        mask[s] = 1;
        queue<int> q;
        q.push(s);
        while(!q.empty()){
            s = q.front();
            q.pop();
            for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
                if(martix[s*n+i]!=0&&mask[i]!=1){
                    cout<<i<<' ';
                    q.push(i);
                    mask[i] = 1;
                }
            }
        }
        cout<<endl;
        delete [] mask;
        delete [] martix;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

test case:

```
1
6 7 0
0 3
0 4
1 4
1 5
2 3
2 4
3 5
```

expected output:

```
0 3 4 2 5 1
```

[image]

Comment: Possible cause: Your `for(int i = 0; i<n*n; i++){` loop completely trashes the heap by writing past `martix`. The last iteration would write to `martix[n * n-1 * n + n]`

Comment: You have a typo in `for(int i = 0; i<n*n; i++){` -> `for(int i = 0; i<n; i++){` causing access out-of-bounds on the arrays and undefined behavior. The loops are also unnecessary. `new int[n*n]()` would initialize all elements to zero as well. Please don't use manual memory allocation with `new` for something like this. It is bad style and will cause you unneeded trouble in the future. Use `std::vector` instead, which will also automatically zero-initialize.

Comment: Immediately after allocating `mask` with `n` elements and `martix` with `n*n` elements, the following loops write to `n*n` elements of `mask` and `n*n*n + n` elements of `martix`.    Writing to more elements of an array than it has gives undefined behaviour.

Comment: Time to break out your debugger...

Comment: Thank you guys，i even don‘t notice that^&^

Answer (score 3):

`i` has the potential to run to `n * n - 1`, and `j` up to `n - 1`

At that point (and before), the expression `i * n + j` which you use as the array index is out of the array bounds. That's undefined behaviour and is manifesting itself (helpfully) as a crash.

Did you mean to run `i` only up to `n`, rather than the square?

Note that if you had use a `std::vector` and the `.at` method rather than `[]` on a bare array the C++ runtime would have thrown an exception, which would be trivial to diagnose and fix.

Comment: @Deatrg: Na, we've all done it. But seriously it is safer to use `.at()`. The amount of bugs I've dodged doing that. Of course if performance really matters (and is the bottleneck) then occasionally you need `[]`, as `.at()` does come with a bounds checking overhead.